# List post titles using wp_query

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to list the post titles using a regular wp_query, just to add the permalink to the a href of the items, this is the code i'm using:

```
    <?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'post_type=artworks_post' );
        // The Loop
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
            echo '<a rel="' .the_permalink(). '" href="' .the_permalink. ' ">';
            the_title();
            echo '</a>';
        endwhile;

        // Reset Post Data
        wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
```

The problem is that the code is not working, it just returns the a href with the word "permalink" but no the link itself.

What i'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Try the_permalink() as href (with parentheses)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to use get_permalink instead of the_permalink. Function the_permalink is printing the permalink itself (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_permalink), but function get_permalink returning the permalink string (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink).

Anyway just a suggestion, use printf instead of echo. such as,

```
<?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'post_type=artworks_post' );
    // The Loop
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
        echo '<a rel="' .the_permalink(). '" href="' .the_permalink. ' ">';
        the_title();
        echo '</a>';
    endwhile;

    // Reset Post Data
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

As requested, I add the example using echo instead of printf

```
<?php
    $the_query = new WP_Query( 'post_type=artworks_post' );
    // The Loop
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
        echo '<a rel="' .get_permalink(). '" href="' .get_permalink(). ' ">';
        the_title();
        echo '</a>';
    endwhile;

    // Reset Post Data
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you!! However I would appreciate if you can also add an example using echo instead of printf, can you?

Comment: I have added example using echo. basically change the_permalink to be get_permalink. Hope it helps. :-)

Comment: thank you, it's exactly what I was looking with the question :)

Answer (score 1):

You missed the parentheses;

```
         echo '<a rel="' .the_permalink(). '" href="' .the_permalink(). ' ">';
        the_title();
        echo '</a>';
```

Answer (score 1):

You used `the_permalink` instead of `the_permalink()` after `href`.

However what you should be using is [`get_permalink()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink), which returns the value for use in your `echo` instead of `echo`ing it immediately.